# apache without file extensions

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I have an Apache server set up on my Ubuntu machine. I recently updated my machine and reinstalled Apache from scratch (although I backed up my config files). Before I updated, I was able to access the file `/var/www/folder/example.html` at `example.com/folder/example` but now typing that into my server links to the file `/var/www/folder/example/index.html` which doesn't exist and so I get a 404 error. If I type in the direct path (`example.com/folder/example.html`) that works, but not without the `.html` at the end. Is there a way to reconfigure Apache so that it works like it used to?

Comment: Did you remember to backup the hidden `.htaccess` file?

Comment: I didn't use any `htaccess` files.. I just configured everything in the `apache2.conf` file

Comment: [Content negociation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_negotiation.html) is now disabled? Try to add `MultiViews` on `Options` lines (ensure first mod_negociation is compiled in or loaded).

Comment: What do you mean by "reinstalled apache from scratch"? Did you recompile it? Did you `apt-get --purge && apt-get install apache2` it?

Answer (score 0):

You might have an issue with having a folder "example" in the same directirt you got the "example.html" file. 
Either you should remove/rename the folders or you could put something like this in either your apache2.conf or the .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! \.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html
```

EDIT:
You need to do as @julp suggest in his comment. Using MultiViews will allow for having different file extensions and calling only for the files basename. Ba aware that it would be wise to have unique basenames in your folder. 
Also, the MultiView setting has to be set per folder.
Have a further look at [negotiation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#negotiation):

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html#negotiation

Comment: I don't have a folder `example` though. I was just saying that that's where Apache is probably looking for a file. Wouldnt that rewrite rule just automatically add `.html` to every URL though? I also have other filetypes that I'd like to access, but by default (without an extension) it should access either `.php` or `.html` files (none of which have the same name)

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess file should look something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
#
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=302,L]
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

If you are running Apache2 or similar engines, make sure you allow overriding in their conf files.

[This is a good tutorial for setting up your conf.](https://www.dyclassroom.com/reference-server/how-to-access-web-page-without-file-extension-apache-htaccess-url-rewrite)

Let me know if that worked for you.